# Python Tkinter : Canvas with Image takes forever to execute

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I've been experimenting a little with the Canvas function of Tkinter and tried to add some imagefile to the window, to test if i can create proper background images.The code so far seems to be working fine (atleast i get no errors when executing). But as soon as i try to execute the Python script it just takes forever to load and doesn't display a window or anything. As soon as i remove the Canvas block from my script it works fine.

```py
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("ImageTest")
root.geometry("350x150")
root.minsize(350,150)
root.maxsize(350,150)

#***** Canvas *****                          
photo = PhotoImage(file="derp.gif")
w = Canvas(root, width=350, height=150)
w.pack()                             
w.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=photo)  
w.image = photo  


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the line `w.image = photo`?

Comment: Yep, just tried to execute it without, still the same, console is just sitting like : $ python test.py and nothing is happening.

Comment: Just tried your code (with my own .gif); works fine.

Comment: Seems to be a local problem then, gonna switch to my Linux machine and see how it goes. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Whatever it is on my Windows machine that is blocking it from being executed... works flawlessly under Linux.

Comment: Odd... I'm using it on Windows 7 and it works fine.

Comment: Windows 8 here.. using git bash, everything i executed in there worked fine so far. just this little Canvas addition to my Gui makes it error? or whatever to call it, it just gets stuck as said.